# How to adjust the Caret (blinking cursor) size inside searchbar with css

Tags: css, searchbar

I tried to google it, and surprisingly found no result related...
I wonder how can I use css to adjust the blinking cursor inside the search box with CSS?
I adjusted the size of the search box, but seem the blinking cursor's size is still original small text size.

Comment: @mrbinky3000 well, this is not an article (as you already know, being over 2k rep) and, if you are aware of newer ways to achieve this goal, answering would be more productive than commenting that someone else should answer... *"Be the change you want to see in the world"*, and all that jazz ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to control cursor/caret size with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090893/how-to-control-cursor-caret-size-with-css)

Answer (score 22):

You cannot change the width of the caret (at least for now);
But you can change the caret color for majority of modern browsers

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/caret-color

```
input {
 caret-color: red;
 caret-color: #ff0000;
 caret-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
 caret-color: hsl(0, 97%, 50%);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Searching for Caret instead of Cursor will give you more results.

Appearently, it is not possible in a textarea, but is possible in other elements through Javascript:

Take a look at:

[How to control cursor/caret size with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090893/how-to-control-cursor-caret-size-with-css)

[How to modify the caret with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240735/how-to-modify-the-caret-with-css)

and

[Styling text input caret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339333/styling-text-input-caret)

Comment: not seem a solution, more of a complex way to deal with simple adjustment. Not going to use them, I will just stay as is, atm I guess......However if anyone else got a better solution that actually extend the size of the Caret to the size that close to the search bar input field itself, will appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to styling the caret currently, but if you use another DOM element to display the input control value then you can. Take a look at [How to use this square cursor in a HTML input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758023/how-to-use-this-square-cursor-in-a-html-input-field)

[image: sample]

Answer (score 3):

If caps is ok in your context, one easy hack is to use the css attribute **font-variant: small-caps;** to get the caret larger than the text.

Another approach is to create your own caret using an input field replacement, someone spent time and [achieved something working](https://benfrain.com/creating-a-custom-input-cursorcaret/), but the author recommend to keep using the standard caret.

Answer (score 2):

As I know, there's no direct way to style the caret.
Instead here's some useful infos that can help you hack your way through this problems.

By default the caret height will take the font height, the only time it will not, is when the line height is specified then it will take this height.

So if you want to modify the caret height you can do it through font-size or through line height if you don't want to change the font size.

Answer (score 0):

There a way, you can change the font-size of the textarea to bigger or smaller, the caret size will change according to it, its not the best way but its a solution

Answer (score -4):

```
<style>
.input_strips {
font-family: monospace;

<!--change the font size this will change the input cursor and the text box-->
font-size: 30px; 
}
</style>
```