# Modify Caret Height

Tags: html, css, height, caret

I have [this](https://jsfiddle.net/g9vo5v0e/) example for my problem.

In there, there is a `<span>` with the attribute `contenteditable` that pretty much is a `input`. The text inserted inside is exactly equal to the 5 lines text "span" (except it's red).

I want the caret (text insertion position cursor vertical bar) to be the height of the green background. In this case, to be 18 pixels height. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVFAl.png) with how it is right now (left side) and how I want it (right side). *look at the red

I don't want a seperated element that looks like the yellow border to be over the caret. Unless you could make the `background-color` green and move the `background-image` on top of the text as transparent and yellow.

**HTML**

`<div style=background:gray><span>span</span><br><span>span</span><br><span>span</span><span id=input contenteditable style="background-image:linear-gradient(green calc(100% - 1px),#fbbc05 1px);color:#ea4335;outline-style:none;width:300px"></span><br><span>span</span><br><span>span</span></div>`

**CSS**

`body{background:#202020;margin:0}
span{color:#fff;display:inline-block;font-family:consolas}`

cowene@30wave.com

Comment: Just add a `padding-bottom: 1px` to your `contenteditable` `span` (https://jsfiddle.net/tj1xodxz/)

Comment: But that will make the line higher.

Comment: If you want the line to have some particular height, use the CSS `height` property (generally, you should specify all your requirements in the original question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well. just change the gradient background to just a `background-color:green` , add a `border-bottom:1px solid #fbbc05` (yellow)

plus add `line-height:20px;font-size:16px` to all spans ( use even numbers because in this case where you need to have exactly exactly pixel-perfect result, if you use odd pixels they might not appear perfectly on the screen )

and add `line-height:19px` to the span#input ( 1px is the border )

see snippet below or **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g9vo5v0e/4/)**

let me know if it works

LATER EDIT :the Caret itself cannot be modified with CSS . you can try making a custom caret . ( see link below and other answers on SO on this subject )

see here [How to adjust the Caret (blinking cursor) size inside searchbar with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249288/how-to-adjust-the-caret-blinking-cursor-size-inside-searchbar-with-css)

```css
body{background:#202020;margin:0}
span{color:#fff;display:inline-block;font-family:consolas;line-height:20px;font-size:16px;}
```

```html
<div style=background:gray><span>span</span><br><span>span</span><br><span>span</span><span id=input contenteditable style="background-color:green;border-bottom:1px solid #fbbc05;color:#ea4335;outline-style:none;width:300px;line-height:19px;"></span><br><span>span</span><br><span>span</span></div>
```

Comment: When I change the `border-bottom` in the JSFiddle to 1px and run the code, it's just like my JSFiddle. [Image](http://i.imgur.com/kyE0StP.png).

Comment: I don't wanna change the font-size because that will make the text smaller.

Comment: well...either you change all the spans and set `font-size:16px`  either you make a custom caret . as the Caret itself cannot be modified with CSS

see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249288/how-to-adjust-the-caret-blinking-cursor-size-inside-searchbar-with-css

Comment: Can you make an example in JSFiddle with either of thoses options? I know that custom carets don't normally work the same and are super complex.

Comment: edited my answer with the changes ( snippet and jsfiddle also ) . check it out

Comment: It's still [different](http://i.imgur.com/zZXv2M1.png). Adding a border makes 1 of 2: add space between the lines; decrease the size of the font.

Comment: As a red-green (partially) color blind person I find your example kinda unhelpful. :'(

Comment: @zrajm sorry. Didn't mean that :) I just used the colors provided by the OP in his question.