# Vertical line cursor is too small compared to text

Tags: css, reactjs

I try create new react app and apply a font (Corporate-Logo-Bold-ver3.woff) it works fine. But when I add to old project react app, the vertical line cursor seem too small than text. Is there any problem with this. [Small vertical line cursor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWNXS.png)

I try to fix line-height,it not work too.

Comment: I'm not aware of the caret _height_ (if that's what you're worried about) being controllable by CSS (at least by standard CSS and not vendor-specific CSS). You might be interested in [CSS drafts.csswg.org/css-ui-4/#caret-shape](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui-4/#caret-shape).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modify Caret Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41551735/modify-caret-height)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.