# Is there a way to make the cursor in a textbox more prominent?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a web app for folks with brain injuries. I'd like to make the cursor in the textbox more noticeable than a think blinking line.

Is there a way to make it larger?

(Searched on Google and SO. No luck)

Comment: If the textbox just has a single line, it's simpler but if it is multiline, I think it's not easy to have an elegant solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092963/can-i-change-the-blinking-caret-in-a-form-text-area-in-a-browser

Comment: @HashemQolami I think he meant about the **caret** blinking in a focused textbox (text input field), not the mouse cursor.

Comment: Check this SO post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249288/how-to-adjust-the-caret-blinking-cursor-size-inside-searchbar-with-css.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik read carefully: *"...in the textbox more noticeable than a thin blinking line."*

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: I know what he meant. What I'm after is OP to edit their post and ask accurate questions.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't naively possible/reliable on all browsers as it's controlled by the OS.  I would suggest a help doc of sorts that links your users to modify their system so that not only yours, but all websites, are easier for them to navigate.

see: http://etc.usf.edu/techease/4all/vision/how-do-i-change-the-cursor-options-in-windows-7/#html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo of how to do it from another post ([Styling text input caret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339333/styling-text-input-caret))

Demo: http://shachi.prophp.org/demo.html

Comment: So your answer is basically identical to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240735/how-to-modify-the-caret-with-css which makes me think we should close this question